# in Perl, using Appconfig I want to be able to include a cfg file in another config file

Tags: perl, include, config, app-config

I've done a lot of research but no luck...

I want to have a config file with some default or generic values in it. Then have other config files INCLUDE that default config, and overwrite variables if needed.

example:

Default.cfg :

```
[${name}]
   bin      = /bin/1   
   tmp_dir  = /tmp
   tmp_file = /tmp/${name}_tmp_file

------------------------------

myProc.cfg :

name  = Test_proc

[${name}]    
   bin   = /bin/TEST
```

This way, myProc.cfg uses the same tmp_dir defined in the default.cfg but defines the "name" and redefines bin dir.

Well, this example is very simple but I have gizillion configs that share the same lines of cfg but differ a little and I'm trying to consolidate configs.

My app is in Perl and already using [AppConfig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AppConfig).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config::General` ought to be able to handle this, but if you wish to stick with `AppConfig`, simply create a subclass, that preprocesses the config file, by manually processing includes , say `s/_my_special_include_syntax = (.+)$/IncludeThis($1)/ge;`
afaik, this should work without any other modifications, since last assignment wins, thus, the last assignment overrides defaults

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up doing something close to this. I created a big config file after reading each included file in order. Then I created my app-config object with that final config file. Since I read the smaller configs in order, the latest one took precedence.

Answer (score 1):

[YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2490892) can handle multiple "documents" in a file. So it's possible to use YAML to separate several `AppConfig` documents.

I haven't done *real* diving into AppConfig, but something like the following should--when tuned--work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use English qw<$RS>;
use YAML qw<LoadFile>;

sub open_strings {
    my @results = map { 
        open( my $h, '<', \$_ );
        $h;
    } @_;
    return wantarray ? @results 
         : @_ == 1   ? $results[0] 
         :             \@results
         ;
}

my @cfgs 
    = map { my $c = AppConfig->new(); $c->file( $_ ); $c } 
      open_strings( LoadFile( $fh_or_fname ))
    ;
```

The code below shows how you can separate them up into documents, *and* that you might not even have to. The third document is a mapping of file to text.

```
--- | 

  [${name}]
     bin      = /bin/1   
     tmp_dir  = /tmp
     tmp_file = /tmp/${name}_tmp_file

--- > 

  name  = Test_proc

  [${name}]    
     bin   = /bin/TEST

---
Default.cfg : |
  [${name}]
     bin      = /bin/1   
     tmp_dir  = /tmp
     tmp_file = /tmp/${name}_tmp_file

Myproc.cfg : | 

  name  = Test_proc

  [${name}]    
     bin   = /bin/TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but I found that AppConfig can be run multiple times.

To publish my files I moved all my login/passwords to configfile.ini.secret and left example login/passwords in configfile.ini

```
$config->define("configFile=s", {DEFAULT=>$dirname."/eversolar.ini"});
$config->args();

// Configfile must exist   
-e $config->configFile or die "Configfile '", $config->configFile, "' not found\n";

// read configfile
$config->file($config->configFile);
pmu_log("Severity 3, Configfile is: " . $config->configFile . "\n");

// Look for secret file
$config->configFile($config->configFile.".secret");
if (-e $config->configFile) {
    $config->file($config->configFile);
    pmu_log("Severity 3, Configfile is: " . $config->configFile . "\n");
}
```

Instead of just hardcoding the .secret, you could daisy-chain the files by having the name of the next file in the previous one.

Something like (and perl syntax is probably wrong)

```
$configFile = $config->configFile;

while (-e $configfile) {
  $config->configFile(""); //do not read any more files
  $config->file($configFile); //after this one.
  $configFile = $config->configFile; // unless the next one is set in this
}
```

Or you could put files in a config.d directory and process all in alfabetical order.